# Update the author/user of acf images after importing via WP All Import

Tags: wordpress

Looking for a solution to assign all child product attachments of a post after importing via WP All Import.
The Image importer works to assign the configured users but the ACF file field doesnt follow the same logic and assigns it as per the user logged in.

Looking for a solution to assign all child product attachments of a post after importing via WP All Import.

The Image importer works to assign the configured users but the ACF file field doesnt follow the same logic and assigns it as per the user logged in.

I have a user security hierarchy which means locks down the media based on the assigned author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will fix it via the functions, only I would love to figure out how to limit it to specific wp imports

```
    <?php
// https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284283/how-can-i-change-an-images-author

add_action('pmxi_saved_post', 'image_author', 10, 1);

function image_author($id) 
{

$user_id = get_post_field ('post_author', $id);


$args = array(
'post_parent' => $id,
'post_type' => 'attachment'
//,
// 'post_mime_type' => 'image'
);

$attachments = get_posts($args);
if($attachments) :
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) : setup_postdata($attachment);
       $the_post = array();
       $the_post['ID'] = $attachment->ID;
       $the_post['post_author'] = $user_id;

       wp_update_post( $the_post );

   endforeach;
endif;    

}

?>
```